# "You should avoid this app" when trying to connect Google Analytics to our app

Tags: c#, angularjs, google-analytics

We are receiving this popup (in multiple browsers, not just Chrome) when our users are trying to connect Google Analytics from inside of our web application. Previously, the user could hit Advanced and just acknowledge the popup and move on, but that isn't possible any longer. If you've received this popup, how did you get around it?

This is an Angular 1.7 app on the client-side and a C# web API on the back-end.

[image]

Comment: Isnt it awesome that google is protecting your users from potentially dangerous apps that may be trying to exploit them.  Apply for application verification for your app will no longer be considered any danger to your users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your app Google Verified, that's the absolute best way to solve it.

You can try adding one of the users (yourself, or someone you can trust?) to the API IAM with the role of "Editor" which should allow **that** person to access it at least.